# Accumulate integers reading data from file in C++11

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, cin, accumulate

I would like to ask how `accumulate` works when you read integers from a file.
Generally `accumulate` takes an iterator that points to the first position of a container and an iterator that points to the last position of the same container (for example a `vector`) and the initial value.
If we need to read data from a file the following piece of code is written

```
ifstream dataFile("ints.dat");
accumulate(istream_iterator<int>(dataFile), istream_iterator<int>(), 0);
```

The temporal iterators that are created are not the iterators of the same containers. I could not understand how this works correctly and does not result in an endless loop.
A possible implementation of `accumulate` is the following :

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        init = init + *first;
    }
    return init;
}
```

Comment: Because you're not dealing with containers here, but a special class which have its own overloaded functions to make it work like an iterator and which recognizes the special "end" object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no containers involved here since you are using stream iterators which have specific behaviors.

When you increment a `istream_iterator`, a value is read from the underlying stream. If something wrong happens while reading (`fail()` returns `true`), then the iterator becomes the *end-of-stream* iterator.

A default constructed `istream_iterator` is always an *end-of-stream* iterator, so both iterators will compare equals only when the increment operator on `istream_iterator` fails to read the next value (at the end of the file, or when something wrong occurs).

---

Some relevant quotes from the standard:

> [[istream.iterator-1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stream.iterators#istream.iterator-1)
>
> After it is constructed, and every time `++` is
>   used, the iterator reads and stores a value of `T`. If the iterator fails to read and store a value of `T` (`fail()` on
>   the stream returns true), **the iterator becomes equal to the *end-of-stream* iterator value.**
>   The constructor with no arguments `istream_iterator()` always constructs an *end-of-stream* input iterator object, which is
>   the only legitimate iterator to be used for the end condition. [...]
>
> [[istream.iterator-2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stream.iterators#istream.iterator-2)
>
> Two end-of-stream iterators are always equal. An end-of-stream iterator is not equal to a non-end-of-stream iterator. [...]

Answer (score 2):

This is the beauty of C++ :-)

To understand this fully we have to understand the difference between a *type* and an *object* and that the symbols (`++`,`!=`) are just functions (albeit specialy defined).

The standard algorithm `accumulate` is defined as:

1. Taking an `iterator` of the beginng of a container,
2. Taking an `iterator` *symbolizing* the end of a container,
3. Taking an intial value

In the shown implemenation the critical part to expalin is:
`first != last`.

This is not a very complicated expression. But what is happening behind the scenes is very interesting.

As we can see the type is an `istream_iterator<int>`. This type has many operations defined on it. One of those operations is the operation `++`(*plus plus* -or- *increment* -or- *move to next position*).  This is quite easy to explain: The call of `++` is as-if defining a function `move_to_next()` for the iterator **type**. Then when the `++` is used it is like calling the function `move_to_next()` for the declared **object**.

In the same way there is a special function `!=` (*exclaimation equals* -or- *not equal*) defined.

For this explaination let's redefine it `bool compare_iterators_not_equal(istream_iterator<int> lhs, istream_iterator<int> rhs)`. This function takes as it's parameters two istream_iterator objects and evaluates if these two objects are *not equal*.

And now to combine this information...

The end iterator object doesn't have to be a physical location in the container. It just has to **symbolize** the end of your container, so that when the iterator objects are compared (by the `compare_iterators_not_equal` function (`!=`)) it will return that the iterator has reached the end.

So the first iterator is defined on the input stream and keeps reading the next data. When it reaches the end of input, then the iterator changes it's state  - to a state signaling that it has reached the end of input. When the iterator in this state is compared with a default constructed iterator (which **symbolizes** end of input) the comparison function knows: it is the the end of input. Then the loop finishes.